# Way to find the value of $ a_{2011}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let us consider the sequence $ a_1 , a_2 , a_3 ,\ldots $ where $ \frac{1}{a_{k+1}} = \frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{a_k}$ for $k >1$ and $a_1 = 2^{2009}$. How can I find the value of $ a_{2011}$?

Comment: I changed $a_1,a_2,a_3,\text{...}$ to $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots$ and $\frac{1}{a_2}+\text{...}+\frac{1}{a_k}$ to $\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_k}$.  Those are standard usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that $ \frac{1}{a_{k+1}} = \frac{1}{a_k} + \frac{1}{a_k}$. This will give you a simple relation between $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$. Unfold it upto $a_1$. You have your answer.